# I can't generate the gRPC stubs classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

I managed to generate the classes through the .proto file but they are in the build.

I would like the classes to be generated within the main because when I am going to extend the stub, it is not being possible to implement the methods.

Look:

File .proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package demogrpcserver.tcp;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.example.demogrpcserver";
option java_outer_classname = "tcp";

service TCPService {
  rpc execute(TCPMonitorRequest) returns (TCPMonitorResponse);
}

message TCPMonitorRequest {
  string socketOpen = 1;
  string messageType = 2;
}

message TCPMonitorResponse {
  bool success = 1;
  string txId = 2;
}
```

The .proto file is inside the main folder.

Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your Java classes anywhere you want with the protoc tool

```
protoc \
  -I PATH_TO_YOUR_PROTOS \
  --java_out=PATH_TO_JAVA_LOCALTION \
  PROTO_FILE_NAME_THAT_WILL_BE_IN_$PATH_TO_YOUR_PROTOS

protoc \
  -I $PATH_TO_YOUR_PROTOS \
  --java_out=$PATH_TO_JAVA_LOCALTION \
  --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=/usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-java \
  PROTO_FILE_NAME_THAT_WILL_BE_IN_$PATH_TO_YOUR_PROTOS
```

Installing the protoc and protoc-grpc-java plugin

```
PROTOC_VERSION="3.12.0"
JAVA_GEN_VERSION="3.7.1"
JAVA_GRPC_GEN_VERSION="1.24.0"


## Protobuf compiler
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y unzip && \
        wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v$PROTOC_VERSION/protoc-$PROTOC_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip && \
        unzip protoc-$PROTOC_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip -d /usr/local/ && \
        rm -rf protoc-$PROTOC_VERSION-linux-x86_64.zip

# Protobuf Java
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/1.27.2/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.27.2-linux-x86_64.exe -o  /usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-java && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-java
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/apssouza22/modern-api-management)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin in the pom file to auto-generate proto files in the src path.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
            <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>

                        <inputDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/resources</include>
                        </inputDirectories>

                        <outputTargets>
                            <outputTarget>
                                <type>java</type>   <outputDirectory>src/proto/</outputDirectory>
                            </outputTarget>
                            <outputTarget>
                                <type>grpc-java</type>
                                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0</pluginArtifact>
                            <outputDirectory>src/proto/</outputDirectory>
                            </outputTarget>
                        </outputTargets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Else with your current setup you can import your proto files and extend it.

Comment: Nice. Got to Gradle?

Comment: implementation group: 'com.github.os72', name: 'protoc-jar-maven-plugin', version: '3.11.4'

Comment: My application is configured with gradle. Do you know how I apply this setting in gradle?

Comment: Hope this helps https://medium.com/@DivyaJaisawal/generate-java-code-from-proto-file-using-gradle-1fb9fe64e046

Comment: @devr, i found one for Gradle https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

Answer (score 0):

See the [Generated Code section](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java#generated-code) of the gRPC Java readme. For non-Android Gradle builds, you'd use:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.15'
}

protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0"
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.36.0'
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
      grpc {}
    }
  }
}
```

You can also take a look at the [grpc-java examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples).